# Switching dark mode using AutoHotKey Error: Parameter #2 of RegWrite is invalid

Tags: autohotkey, darkmode

Using AutoHotKey v2 and [the following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59335964/how-to-edit-registry-values-with-autohotkey) I am trying to switch my dark mode on my windows machine.

AutoHotKey introduced a new syntax in v2 which I am trying to translate. Resulting in the following script:

```
^!r::
{
    valueType := "REG_DWORD"
    keyName := "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize"
    valueName := "AppsUseLightTheme"
    appMode := RegRead(keyName, valueName)

    ; MsgBox(appMode)
    If (appMode = 0) ; dark
        RegWrite(valueType, keyName, valueName, 1)
    else   ; If (appMode = 1) light 
        RegWrite(valueType, keyName, valueName, 0)
}
```

However an error message on the keyName when writing the value to the registry:

```
Error: Parameter #2 of RegWrite is invalid.

Specifically: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize

    006: appMode := RegRead(keyName, valueName)
    008: If (appMode = 0)
▶   009: RegWrite(valueType, keyName, valueName, 1)
    010: Else
    011: RegWrite(valueType, keyName, valueName, 0)
```

which would suggest the keyName is invalid. It does work however on the read.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right syntax for [RegWrite](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/RegWrite.htm) is

> **RegWrite Value, ValueType, KeyName , ValueName**

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

^!r::
{
    valueType := "REG_DWORD"
    keyName := "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize"
    valueName := "AppsUseLightTheme"
    appMode := RegRead(keyName, valueName)

    ; MsgBox(appMode)

    If (appMode = 0) ; dark
        RegWrite 1, ValueType, KeyName , ValueName
    else   ; If (appMode = 1) light 
        RegWrite 0, ValueType, KeyName , ValueName
}
```

Comment: Right, reading the correct library version helps. Thank you very much this is exactly what I needed.